# Can't deploy Azure web application 'NoRegisteredProviderFound'

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-web-app-service

I use to be able to just publish my web application in visual studio without any problem but now whenever I try to publish I get this error message

[image: error message azure]

I can still publish my project but my database doesn't get create so I can't publish that.

Comment: Make sure your web app and database are in the same region